# Why is fprintf not printing the full data in file even after flushing?

Tags: c, printf

I am using sieve method to print all the prime numbers to a file. My code is as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    FILE* file = fopen("primeList.txt","w+");
    bool* x;
//  long upLimit=100;
    long upLimit=2000000000;    
    x=(bool*) calloc(1,upLimit);
    long i=upLimit;
    while(i--){
        *(x+i)=true;
    }
    *(x+1)=false;
    *(x+2)=true;
    *(x+3)=true;
    int cnum=2;
    int count=0;
    while(cnum<upLimit){
        if(*(x+cnum)){
            fprintf(file, "%d\n",cnum);
            count++;
            int compNum=cnum*2;
            while(compNum<upLimit){
                *(x+compNum)=false;
                compNum+=cnum;
            }
        }
        cnum+=1;
    }
    fprintf(file, "Count is : %d\n", count);
    fflush(file);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

The last few lines from *outfile* is as below:

[image]

I am expecting count of primes to be the last line.
Please help with the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have enough disk space?

Comment: For enquiring minds, fixed, this should produce the last two lines as `1999999973` and `Count is : 98222287`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running the code with debug symbols, I can observe on my machine that it is reliably segfaulting at line 26: `*(x+compNum)=false;`

Issuing `p compNum` in gdb gives us the clue: `compNum` has overflown to negative and now the code is trying to reference memory address that's not within process limits.

In other words, the output is not cut at the "Count" but earlier, in the middle of `fprintf` in your system (and mine).

Answer (score 0):

Possible wrong size allocation.

Code assumes `bool` is size 1.

```
bool* x;
long upLimit=2000000000;    

//x=(bool*) calloc(1,upLimit);
// Should be 
x = calloc(sizeof *x, upLimit);

// Add test
if (x) {
  long i=upLimit;
  while(i--){
    *(x+i)=true;
  }
```